# How to make a View Controller for iPhone 4s or iPhone 4 with iOS 6 sdk?

Tags: ios, ios6, xcode4.5

I have recently upgraded to iOS6 SDK and XCode 4.5...
I don't know how to design views for iPhone 4S and below as the screen size is smaller for the devices compared to iphone 5. when we create a new project with ios6 in Xcode 4.5 and drag a viewcontroller to the storyboard, its size is 1136 X 640.... So how to design 960X640 apps for iphone 4s with Xcode 4.5 and ios 6sdk??

Answer (score 10):

There is two method to do that

1. Open storyboard , go to Editor tab on the top and tap "Apply retina 3.5 form factor ".
2. There is a button on the bottom right corner also (on side of zoom button) to change the storyboard size.

Hope that helps.

Comment: 2 was helpful! How come I didn't notice it

Comment: how did you find that button? I cant seem to find the zoom button. All I see on the bottom of my storyboard is a panel which contains wCompact hAny

Answer (score 3):

In case you are not using Storyboard, following are the steps:

1. Click on the UIView in Interface Builder
2. Select Attribute Inspector for this UIView
3. In Simulated Matrix, change value for Size as Retina 3.5 Full Screen.

Hope that helps